# How to create a directory in Oracle in Windows desktop

Tags: oracle

I need to create an oracle directory in Windows desktop `C:\Users\slopegar\Desktop`. I have tried `create directory image_files as 'C:\Users\slopegar\Desktop\images'` but don't work.

EDIT: Don't appear any error in the execution (`Directory IMAGE_FILES creado.` ) but the directory is no created-in desktop. The Oracle Server is local for tests.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *but the directory is no created in desktop*

`CREATE DIRECTORY` creates a "directory object" inside the database.

It does **not** create a physical directory in the filesystem of the Oracle server:

[Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207)

> For file storage, **you must also create a corresponding operating system directory** [...] Oracle Database does not verify that the directory you specify actually exists. Therefore, take care that you specify a valid directory in your operating system.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So you need to create the directory on your hard disk manually.

Answer (score 2):

"Don't work" is less than descriptive. What happened when you tried it?

Anyway: a directory, as an Oracle object, (ideally) has to reside on the database server. If not, the server has to have access to it (hint: you'd use UNC to create such a directory).

So, if your own computer is the database server (for example, if you run Oracle 11g XE on it), then creating a directory in such a manner (the one you used) should work. Otherwise, it most probably won't.

How did you create that directory? Did you connect as SYS? If not, you should have.

Also, as you didn't mention it: did you grant required privileges on that directory to user(s) which will be using it? For example,

```
grant read, write on directory image_files to scott;
```

Comment: My own computer is the database server, specifically Oracle 11g XE. Yes, I granted the directory and it was executed correctly, but still don't appear.

Comment: What does it mean, "still don't appear"? What do you exactly expect to achieve by creating a directory? It is - once again - an **Oracle object**. That command (`create directory ...`) won't create a directory on your desktop. Directory on the desktop should already exist; Oracle *directory* just points to the file system directory and lets you manipulate files stored within (for purposes of datapump export and import, external tables feature, UTL_FILE, etc.).

Comment: Ok, that was the problem, I didn't create my images directory in desktop. Thanks for the clarification Littlefot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a physical directory when you want to create a oracle directory with CREATE DIRECTORY.

This directory is a oracle object, it is not a Windows directory so, you cant see in your desktop.